# Change change mode of all files and folders in CPanel at once?

Tags: cpanel

I have a deluxe hosting with GoDaddy and have uploaded WordPress websites in it. However, nowadays someone is hacking into my website (even after changing the cpanel and ftp passwords) and uploading files which include a zip file, and after they extract the zip file it will have N number of files as a result my hosting resource is getting overflown.

I keep on deleting the files and reuploading a fresh copy but they again do the same. Since it's WordPress I have to change permission of a number of folders which is impossible. Please guide me about how to change the permission at once.  I also tried FileZilla to change permission but it's shown to be changed in FileZilla and when I check back with CPanel file manager, it's still the same permission.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use File Zilla and log in with your cPanel credentials. When you right-click, there is an option for file permission; Inside this option, you will find Recursive File & Folder Permissions! Voila.. Job Done!

Comment: It takes forever if you're doing a lot of file/folders recursively though.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change all files and directory permission recursively through cPanel, if you have shall access of your account then you can change it through SSH, Otherwise you need to contact your hosting provider to update it.

Also, I will suggest you please remove your all files from public_html directory and upload all fresh files, Might be there is shell scripts present in your account and due to you are facing this issues.

Once you upload your files, Please secure your word-press with the following steps.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Sites that give cpanel access typically give ftp access. You can use `lftp` the smart ftp client to do the job. I did `brew install lftp` in my macbook then use the following snippet to change the file permission:

```
lftp <<EOF
set ftp:ssl-allow no
set ftp:passive-mode true
set ftp:list-options -a
open -u xxx,yyy zzz.host.com
chmod -R 0777 /public_html/concrete575/application/files/
EOF
```

where `xxx` is my username, `yyy` is my password, and `zzz.host.com` is the ftp host.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I managed to get it done by uploading a simple recursive PHP script to change permissions to all files within the desired directory.

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: @Tayyebi, sorry it's been too long and I lost that bit of code by now. However, I found this similar question that you may find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262622/set-permissions-for-all-files-and-folders-recursively